# Number of affected rows Zend DB (UPDATE)

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, count

I'm new to Zend Framework and I'd like to know how I can get the number of affected rows from this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE auth SET act='', status='1' WHERE username = ? AND act = ? ";
$stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($this->username, $this->key));
```

I saw a few posts on this forum, but they we based on MySQLi and SELECT statements where you can actually count the rows using `count()`.

Can anyone suggest how I can alter this to support `rowCount`.

This is how I connect to my database:

```
$parameters = array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname' => 'users'
);

try {
        $db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', $parameters);
...
```

This is in my `Bootstrap.php`. I did it this way because I work with more than one databases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo has a rowCount() method.

See the [API docs](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/db_Db_Statement_Pdo.html#%5CZend_Db_Statement_Pdo)

> Returns the number of rows affected by the execution of the last INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE statement executed by this statement object.

This means you can simply:-

```
$rowsAffected = $stmt->rowCount();
```

Straight after calling execute() and you should get the number of rows affected.

Comment: I have just edited my question to include DB connection. Thank you

Comment: My solution should work for you as [Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/db_Db_Statement_Pdo.html#%5CZend_Db_Statement_Pdo) has a rowCount() method.

Comment: Thanks. It does work. I tried to apply `rowCount()` on the wrong object. Thank you :-)

Comment: Note that rows affected could be fewer than rows matched, if you `UPDATE` them to the same values they were before.  There's no way to know the number of rows matched.