# Zend Framework - counting number of fields in select clause?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm investigating Zend Framework and currently shucked in counting resulting fields of sql query...

In MySQL we can easily check with

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,email FROM people WHERE id = '42'");

/* returns 2 because id,email === two fields */
echo mysql_num_fields($result);
```

I want this in zend framework so please help me on this..

Comment: what you have tried in zend ?

Comment: you can get answer with simple count() as i answered.

Comment: check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132162/number-of-affected-rows-zend-db-update

Comment: that returns number of rows mr Mubo ! not the number of fields !

Answer (score 0):

well if you do not want to use `mysql_num_fields` you can do an alternate way as following,

i don't know how syntax accurate is it, but gets the result for you

```
           public function getuser(){
            $sql=$this->select()
                ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                ->from(array('t'=>'usermaster'),array('email','id'))      
                ->where("id=42");                                         

                $row=$this->fetchRow($sql);

                if (!$row) {
                   throw new Exception("Could not find row $id");
                }

                $return=$row->toArray();
                echo count($return);
}
```

You can define above function in a `model` and call it from a `controller`.

you can also pass dynamic values instead of just 42, by passing id to the function.

Hope that helps.